# display data from sqlite database in listbox and use id to delete it

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have a table in my db with following output when I fetch all lines:

```
(1, 'Type in your Note', '1592897997.43793')
(2, 'Type in your Note', '1592898130.55058')
(3, 'Type in your Note', '1592898180.61336')
(4, 'Type in your Note', '1592898180.83751')
(5, 'Type in your Note', '1592898222.27298')
(6, 'Type in your Note', '1592898222.43869')
```

in the fetch all method i insert them to the listboy as following

```
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
        listbox.insert(END, row)
```

The output in the Listbox is the following. I want just the text to be in the listbox and I need the ID to delete the single Items. Does someone have an idea how i can do that?

[image]

Comment: Is the content of second column (the text) unique (ie no duplicate) in the table?  If yes, you can just use it to delete the required record in the table.

Comment: @acw1668 nope its not unique

Comment: Then you need to create a list to store the IDs (with same order as Listbox).  When removing item from the `Listbox`, get the ID in the ID list (based on the index of selected item in Listbox) to remove record in the table and delete the ID from the ID list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you get the data from an Sql-Statement. Hence if you want to specifiy the content put into your listbox I would edit that Sql-Statement.

Instead of selecting everything from the Sqllite Databse:

```
rows=con.execute(„SELECT * FROM example“)
```

You select only the thing you need:

```
rows=con.execute(„SELECT text FROM example“)
```

After that your current code should work fine.

```
for row in rows:
  print(row)
  listbox.insert(END, row)
```

To delete the selected object create a seperate list like @acw1668 described

> Then you need to create a list to store the IDs (with same order as
> Listbox). When removing item from the Listbox, get the ID in the ID
> list (based on the index of selected item in Listbox) to remove record
> in the table and delete the ID from the ID list

Comment: Sounds good. but deleting an item through the Listbox is hard cause i have no ID of the item. Do you have an idea how i can solve that

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for the correction. I edited my post accordingly and quoted your solution hope that's okay.

Comment: This won't work the way you expect if the value from the row has a space or other special characters in it, like in the question. If if you only select a single column, you'll still get back a list of lists. You're inserting a list into a listbox, but the listbox expects a string. Tkinter will try to convert the list to a string using its own rules, which will result in curly braces in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list that maps listbox indexes to ids. It would look something like this:

```
db_ids = []
for row in rows:
    (db_id, text, something_else) = row
    listbox.insert(END, text)
    db_ids.append(db_id)
```

With that, you can get any database id by index (eg: `db_ids[0]`, `db_ids[1]`, etc)

You must take care to remove corresponding items from the list when you remove items from the listbox.